# Javascript Populate 2 textboxes from single dropdown

Tags: javascript, variables

I have the following code, I think it is close but I'm missing something.

```
var mydropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
mydropdown.onchange = function(){
     var fullString = this.value;

     var mySplitResult = fullString.split(".");\
     for(i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++){
        document.getElementById('a') + i.value = mySplitResult[i]);
      }
}
```

The HTML is the following:

```
<select id="dropdown">
    <option value="">None</option>
    <option value="1220.2440">1220x2440</option>
    <option value="640.480">640x480</option>
</select>

<p>Sheet Size <input id="a0" name="a0" size="10"> X <input id="a1" name="a1" size="10" /></p>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried including the `i` variable inside the `getElementById` method? Something like: `document.getElementById('a' + i).value = mySplitResult[i]);`

Comment: You are making a minor mistake, include the i in the bracket, change this line, `document.getElementById('a' + i).value = mySplitResult[i]);`

Comment: After reviewing your code, take a look as [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5D3Uf/2/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your code:

1. As @faino and @Mustafa said, you are not targeting your text inputs as it's missing their id complements (the integer you put to diferentiate them, 0 and 1).
2. There's a `)` left at the end of that same line.

So the update javascript code is:

```
// try to use addEventListener,
// so you can add more than one listeners for the same event
mydropdown.addEventListener("change", function(){
     var fullString = this.value;

     var mySplitResult = fullString.split(".");

     for(i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++){
        document.getElementById('a' + i) = mySplitResult[i];
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function has small mistakes one is argument of getElementById function and one I mentioned bellow as comment.

```
function(){
         var fullString = this.value;

         var mySplitResult = fullString.split(".");

         for(i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++){
            document.getElementById('a' + i).value = mySplitResult[i];  //Here was a ')' which was causing syntax error.
          }
}
```